# RSpec Exception

Tags: ruby, multithreading, rspec

I am creating an RSpec test to verify data retrieved from a webpage. I call the URL to the webpage and then verify that the data returned is correct. However, part of the test involves resetting the backend, thus, there is a short amount of time during which the server is unreachable. I would like to have an RSpec test that expects the data returned to be the expected contents. However, I get a connection refused exception during the small time the server is resetting and this exception causes the entire test to fail. I would like to somehow perform an RSpec expect and ignore all exceptions that are thrown. For example (pseudocode):

```
Thread.new{"reset server code"}
wait_until{expect("retrieve server url data code").to eq("expected data").and ignore all exceptions()}
```

There is a specifc state the server will be in during the reset cycle, and because of this, I start a thread and wait for the expected data to be returned during that state. This is why I do not wait for the reset to complete and then hit the URL. Any thoughts on how to perform an expect on something and ignore all exceptions would be great. I do not use .to raise_error because due to timing issues I am unsure as to how many times I will receive the exception during my wait_until (note, this is a wrapper to perform the code until the expectation is achieved). I would *ideally* like to just wait until the data returned is correct and ignore all exceptions during the process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe the simplest approach would be to `rescue` from the connection error and `retry`:

```
begin
  expect("retrieve server url data code").to eq("expected data")
rescue SomeConnectionError
  sleep 1
  retry
end
```

The `retry` keyword is documented [here](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.1/doc/syntax/exceptions_rdoc.html).

> You may retry rescued exceptions:
>
> ```
> begin
>   # ...
> rescue
>   # do something that may change the result of the begin block
>   retry
> end
> ```
>
> Execution will resume at the start of the begin block, so be careful
>   not to create an infinite loop.

Comment: I was unfamiliar with that syntax. Thanks for the help, it solved my problem!